# SQLite: - find week of the month

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, datetime, week-number

I need to extract the week of the month i.e. 1-5 from the date. I am using below formula in python.

```py
df['Week_no_Month']= ((df.DATE.dt.day-1)//7+1)
```

Now I want this implemented in SQLite.

Comment: Please define what YOU mean by "week of the month".

Comment: What is the first week of a month, say if the month starts on a Wednesday?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that the week is the day divided by 7, then:

```
select (strftime('%d', dt.day) + 6 / 7)
```

SQLite is flexible about mixing strings and numbers, so you don't need an explicit conversion -- although you might want to include that:

```
select (cast(strftime('%d', dt.day) as int) + 6 / 7)
```